# Ordering JSON rendered by Rails controller

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations, render, nested-attributes

I have a Rails 3.1 controller that renders a user's contacts, including associated email objects and message objects. If I am only rendering the contacts, I can do the following:

```
    @contacts = @current_user.contacts.order('last_name asc', :include => [:emails, :messages])
    render json: @contacts, :include => [:emails, :messages]
```

As you can see, I want to sort the contacts by last name rather than the default id. I am now needing to render the user object with other associated objects as well. So I have tried the following, but of course the contacts are not in the appropriate order:

```
    render :status => 200, :json => {
      :user => @current_user.as_json(
        :include => {
          :foos => {
            :except => :user_id
          },
          :contacts => {
            :except => :user_id,
            :include => [:emails,:messages]
          },
          :bars => {
            :except => :user_id
          }
        }
      )
    }
```

I didn't see any help in the [as_json documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json), and I haven't been able to find the right syntax by trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would order the contacts in Ruby / SQL and just build your own JSON to render instead of using as_json and its various `:include` / `:except` methods.

Build a hash of your data and then send it along to render.

There are all sorts of libraries that can make building JSON easier. [JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) is one such library. Look at the bottom of the JBuilder page for links to other similar libraries.

Comment: I ended up using [json_builder](https://github.com/dewski/json_builder). Exactly what I was looking for. Cut my rendering time by about 55%, not to mention the added transparency.